# Selenium: SafariDriver not opening in MacOSX Sierra

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, safaridriver

I have the latest Selenium, OSX and Safari versions but I'm unable to open Safari Driver using a code as simple as this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

public class SafariDriverDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver;
        driver = new SafariDriver();

        String baseURL = "https://www.google.com";

        driver.get(baseURL);
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        driver.quit();
}

}
```

- What I get in the console is the following: "Password:Password:Password:"
- And regardless of what password I write, the console displays: [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFu7Z.jpg)

This despite me having enabled 'Allow Remote Automation'. I've tried authorising the driver from the Terminal by typing '/usr/bin/safaridriver'and this is the result

```
Could not start server: must specify at least one configuration argument.

Usage: safaridriver [options]
-h, --help                Prints out this usage information.
-p, --port                Port number the driver should use. If the server
                          is already running, the port cannot be changed.
                          If port 0 is specified, a default port will be used
```

I don't know what action to take from here, maybe the issue can be fixed from the console.

Comment: Please mention the actual version numbers. The "latest" has changed since May 4, 2017. The answer to your question may differ as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `/usr/bin/safaridriver -p 0`